# Sketches of $m(a)=\mathbb E[X-(X-a)_+]$ and $v(a)=\mathbb V[X-(X-a)_+]$ for $X\sim Ber(p)$

Tags: random-variables, expected-value

Let $X\sim Ber(p),\ \ \ p \in (0,1)$

Define $m(a)=\mathbb E[X-(X-a)_+],\ \ \ v(a)=\mathbb V[X-(X-a)_+]$
I want to draw sketches of $m(a)$ and $v(a)$

We have

$m(a)=\begin{cases}p,&a\ge X\\a,&a<X\end{cases}$

$v(a)=\begin{cases}p(1-p),&a\ge X\\a,&a<X\end{cases}$

$X$ can only take values in $\{0,1\}$. So we have

$m(a)=\begin{cases}p,&a\ge 1\\a,&a<0\end{cases}$

And for $a \in [0,1)$ we have $m(a)=\begin{cases}p,&X= 0\\a,&X=1\end{cases}$

Am I missing something? How should I draw this

Comment: Are you just looking at $a \in [0,1]$?

Comment: @Ian The task doesn't specify this but it says 'Which interval for $a$ is interesting for the sketches?'

Comment: @Ian do you have an idea?